# Чем можно задеплоить Java EE проект на удаленный сервер?

Tags: java, java-ee, непрерывная-интеграция

Хотелось, чтоб после пуша в репозиторий, исходный код деплоился из репозитория на тестовый сервер и там происходила его сборка + прогон тестов.
Подскажите тулзы для автоматизации подобных действий, с которыми можно было бы быстро разобраться новичку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужен инструмент для continuous integration, например Jenkins, Hudson, CruiseControl и т.д.

Comment: TeamCity, Bamboo, Travis CI туда же